# ArgoCD in EKS: Auth using an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-eks, argo

I have ArgoCD deployed in my EKS cluster. EKS has AWS OIDC identity provider associated with it. Here is ArgoCD helm chart that I'm using: [argo-helm](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm)

I know that Argo supports OIDC authorization.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
A developer can log in to ArgoCD using an AWS account, and do something in argo if this account has certain IAM permissions.
Any suggestions? I was thinking about Cognito, but didn’t figured out how to  link AWS accounts with user pools.